# Dynamic Form Post Method on html with array in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a view that with a modal opens a barcode scanner and every time that I scan a barcode I call a function startScanning() dynamically I'm building inputs inside a form.
When I click submit button I would like to send an array with all the barcodes the problem is that I'm not sure how to call the controller or what I should add in the Action in order to send the array or I if I need to change something in the elements.

My Modal Footer View

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
(What I should write here to pass the array in the action)?
 <form action="~/PurchaseOrder/ReceivedFromBarCode" method="post">

                            <label for="fname">Barcode:</label>
                            <div id="scanned-result" style="margin-bottom: 25px;"></div>

                            <div class="box-footer">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                         <i class="fa fa-paper-plane">
                              </i> Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Javascript Function

```
function startScanning(facingMode) {
        console.log(facingMode)
        var results = document.getElementById('scanned-result');

        var lastMessage;
        var codesFound = 0;
        function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
            if (lastMessage !== qrCodeMessage) {
                lastMessage = qrCodeMessage;
                ++codesFound;
                results.innerHTML += '<br><input placeholder="' + qrCodeMessage +']"  name="barcode[' + codesFound + ']"  type="text" id="barcode' + codesFound + '" value="' + qrCodeMessage + '" >';

               
                            
            }
        }
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
         public async Task<ActionResult> ReceivedFromBarCode(string[] barcode)

        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction($"Details");
            }
            catch (VTHIS.CommunicationException cex)
            {
                throw cex;
            }

        }
```

Elements Console

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                        <form action="/secure/specialapp/admin/PurchaseOrder/ReceivedFromBarCode" method="post">
                            <label for="fname">Barcode:</label>
                            <div id="scanned-result" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                               <br>
                              <input placeholder="https://www.kwch.com"  name="barcode[1]" type="text" id="barcode1" value="https://="www.kwch.com"><br>
                              <input placeholder="http://www.qrstuff.com"  name="barcode[2]" type="text" id="barcode2" value=" http://www.qrstuff.com">
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Use form-binding. Define a view-model class with `public String Barcode { get; set; }` (why are you using a `string[]` array?) and change your POST action method to use that as the parameter, and use `HtmlHelper.InputFor` extension methods to render appropriate inputs.

Comment: That is great thank you so much I understand your concept  Do yo have a example of how the html code should looks like?

Comment: You don't need to write any HTML. Use `HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor` or whatever and it will generate the HTML for you.